# Identify type of regex pattern

Tags: android, regex, android-edittext, android-inputtype

In my application I am adding edittext based on response provided by server. For each edittext server also provides regex pattern to match. I am able to successfully able to match pattern and do validations. But I want to identify type of regex pattern so that I can open keyboard according to value edittext should accept.

For example,
If edittext should accept email address then keyboard with @ sign opens up and if edittext accept numeric values it should open numeric keypad.

Is there any library which can return type from its regex pattern such as "Email", "Number" etc. from regular expressions as there can be several different types of regex pattern?

EDIT: I know how to set input type for edittext but I need to find out type from regex pattern. I am not able to make changes in server I have to handle this on client side.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the input type to change based on a certain regex pattern?

Comment: Yes and my regex pattern will be coming from server and there can be different regex pattern for each edittext.

Comment: So, you want to know the regex patterns or you want to know how to change the input types so the keyboard will change?

Comment: I know how to change input type for keyboard but first thing is I need to identify from regex pattern that what can be ideal values for that edittext and based on that I can set input type. So I need a way that helps me to identify whether it is email or phone number from regex pattern.

Comment: @Rahil2952 you wrote the regex patterns, why don't you send along the regex pattern the "type"?The type is of course predefined with the regex since you wrote it. Detecting the type of regexes afterwards is backwards and also impossible for "all cases", difficult for "most cases".

Comment: @HamZa I haven't written regex pattern. I am getting those as response by using 3rd party services so I don't even have any way to change that response as well.

Comment: @Rahil2952 I would analyse what you get from those 3rd party services and insert a predefined list in your app which routes to each regex you might get. This also means you would need a default behaviour in case the regex isn't in your list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There most probably isn't one. The reason is - there is no way to tell for sure. Anything you can come up with will be heuristic.

### Heuristic one:

1. If the pattern looks for something containing a *dot*, followed by **@** sign, followed by something containing a *dot* - it's an email validation.
2. If the pattern contains only `\d`, or number ranges (`[1-5]`), or single numbers (`7`) plus repetition meta characters (`?`, `*`, `+`, `{4, 12}`), it's a number validation.
3. If the pattern contains `\w` and no **@** sign, it's a regular text.
4. Continue in the same spirit.

   - + high control. You can always add new guesses when you see that your results aren't accurate in some case
   - - requires more code to implement
   - - requires very good knowledge of regexes

### Heuristic two:

Use a list of strings, which you know the type of and try to match them with the regex. Aka, for emails try `example@gmail.com`.

- + easy to implement. Small chance problematic logic
- - least amount of control. If the server is giving you email patterns for different domains you can't guess that this is an email pattern, unless you know all possible domains

### Heuristic three:

Use a library that can generate example strings from regex and match them with your own regexes to determine the type. Here is one for [Java](https://github.com/mifmif/Generex) and another one for [JavaScript](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js).

- + gives a good combination of high control and easy implementation
- - you still have to write your own regexes (not as trivial as the 2nd heuristic)
- - people sometimes write regexes that allow some false positives. Therefore, generated strings might not be in the perfect format (not as much control as the 1st heuristic)

---

### Are the regexes static?

- If yes - you should make a mapping and use that.
- If no - use a heuristic like one of the above and improve it over time as you gain more statistics about how the generated regexes usually look.

Comment: @ndn Your answer doesn't provide an exact solution that I am looking for but your answer is closest to what I require so I am awarding you bounty. Thank you for all your help.